# Kivy: Reset/Default values to all widgets on a screen?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to return all values of all widgets on a screen to their default values (ex. TextInputs text: '') or do I have to write a function to go through each one, one by one, to clear them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Kivy properties retain any concept of a default value, so you'll have to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is clear all widgets on a screen using `.clear_widgets()` function. I don't think there's any way to reset all values. Another way to change the values is like if you have a textfield then you can do `textfield.text = ''` but you have to go through each widget to reset it